# Google Spreadsheet XPATH: Cant extract element that have no data/value

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

from this [link](https://int.soccerway.com/national/england/premier-league/20172018/regular-season/r41547/tables/) i want to get rank position sign, i get image links using this:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://int.soccerway.com/national/england/premier-league/20172018/regular-season/r41547/tables/","//table[@class='leaguetable sortable table detailed-table']//tr/td[@class='direction']/img/@src")
```

yes, i get img url.

```
https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/678/img/delta_plus.gif
https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/678/img/delta_min.gif
https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/678/img/delta_plus.gif
https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/678/img/delta_min.gif
https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/678/img/delta_min.gif
https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/678/img/delta_plus.gif
https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/678/img/delta_min.gif
```

but how to get `<td class="direction"></td>` that has no element inside?

some element have img tag like this:

```
<td class="direction"><img src="https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/678/img/delta_plus.gif" width="7" height="4" title="Previous rank: 4" alt="Previous rank: 4"></td>
```

the other element has no img tag inside:

```
<td class="direction"></td>
```

how to get element that have no data inside so i can get the list like this:

```
https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/678/img/delta_plus.gif
https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/678/img/delta_min.gif



https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/678/img/delta_plus.gif


https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/678/img/delta_min.gif
https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/678/img/delta_min.gif

https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/678/img/delta_plus.gif
https://s1.swimg.net/gsmf/678/img/delta_min.gif
```

what should i do? Thanks

Comment: i also tried with `=IMPORTXML("https://int.soccerway.com/national/england/premier-league/20172018/regular-season/r41547/tables/","//table[@class='leaguetable sortable table detailed-table']//tr/td[contains(@class,'direction') and contains(text(),'')]/img/@src")` and stil only give me img url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to retrieve both `<td class="direction"></td>` and `<td class="direction"><img ... /></td>`. When `td` has no `<img ... />`, you want to put the empty row. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? `https://int.soccerway.com/national/england/premier-league/20172018/regular-season/r41547/tables/` is put in "A1".

#### Modified formula :

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[@class='direction' and not(*)] | //td[@class='direction']/img/@src")
```

- `//td[@class='direction' and not(*)]` means that `td` is `class` with `direction` and without the child elements.
- `//td[@class='direction']/img/@src` means that `td` has the child element of `img`, and retrieve `@src`.

By these, when `td` of `@class='direction'` has the child element of `img`, `@src` is retrieved. When `td` of `@class='direction'` has no the child elements, the empty is put.

#### Result :

[image]

#### Note :

- You can also use `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//table[@class='leaguetable sortable table detailed-table']//tr/td[@class='direction' and not(*)] | //table[@class='leaguetable sortable table detailed-table']//tr/td[@class='direction']/img/@src")`.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: This is what actualy i'm looking for, thank you @Tanaike to try understand my question.

Comment: @dany I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.